# C Abstract data type pointer - Program modularity

Tags: c, struct, abstract-data-type

If some module depends from some other sub-module, either including it in its header or in its code file, And what if modules, besides contributing to the main program, are also mutually dependent?

The figure below schematically illustrates a situation in which module1.h/.c requires a sub-module module4.h, and module2 requires module3.

[image: Example]

Each header file has their own typedef struct exemple:

```
typedef struct list * List;
```

and the source file related to the header files implement the struct like :

```
struct list {
    unsigned length;
    char * value;
};
```

I got another struct in a header file:

```
typedef enum {START, END, MIDDLE, COMMENTS, CONDITIONS} TypeListBal;
typedef struct bal * Bal;
```

and source file :

```
struct bal {
    TypeListBal type;
    List name;              // Name of the bal
    List attributes[];          // Array of type struct List
};
```

I've been reading a lot tonight and I'm not quite sure about one thing. If I'm just including the header file in the source file that I need in my case, I'm including list.h in bal.c cause my bal.c got a struct definition which as member of type List.

To make it work, do I have to put specific #INCLUDE in all my modules or will the job be done at the compilation?

I mean in make makefile, to have my bal.o object, it will look like:

```
bal.o: list.o bal.c bal.h
       $(CC)   -g -W -Wall -c  list.o bal.c bal.h
```

So as soon the makefile try to compile bal.o, the compiler will see all the dependencies, and will be able to compile everything.

That's how I did understand but when I try this, I get:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I'm guessing it's because in my bal.c file, I'm declaring variable of type struct List and the compiler doesn't have any ideas about struct List cause the definition of struct list is in the list.c file.

So the question again is: ***How do I connect everything to make it work?***

Comment: Why did you have the struct bal in the source file instead of having in the header where you have the typedef?

Comment: That's a work, the teacher give us the header files and we can't change anything to thoses header files. So i had to define every struct in their own source file.

I know that i can create an other header files and include all my struct definition in it and include this haeder file in all my source files but im pretty sure there's an other way to compile everything

Comment: Try removing bal.h from the makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header file is broken. This is an incomplete type:

```
typedef struct bal * Bal;
```

It needs the `struct` declaration to make it complete. That ought to be in the header file, too. If in C code you say `*Bal` without the complete type, the compiler gives up because it doesn't have any information about what this expression means, i.e. the fields of the struct.

There should be absolutely no problem with the dependency graph you're showing. You want to use guards to ensure header files are included only once. Then you can include one header from another, and the C preprocessor will "just work" as long as there are no cyclic dependencies.  In your case, the header for e.g. module 4 would look like:

```
// module4.h
#ifndef MODULE_4_H_INCLUDED
#define MODULE_4_H_INCLUDED

#include "module1.h"

// all public type declarations for module 4 types

#endif // MODULE_4_H_INCLUDED
```

Make all the headers (including module1.h) similar, with their own guard definitions. Then the module 4 code:

```
// module4.c
#include "module4.h"

// Use module 4 types.
```

In general, if you need types given by a header file in some `.c` file, include it even if it would be included by dependencies between headers. The guards will generally ensure no redundancy.

Additionally, your idea of make dependencies is incorrect. E.g. to compile `module4.c` successfully to obtain `module4.o`, you need (of course) `module4.c`, `module4.h`, and `module1.h`.  Those are the build dependencies. So the rule will be:

```
module4.o : module4.c module4.h module1.h
        $(CC) -g -W -Wall -c module4.c
```

But you should not write specific rules like this. Make has built-ins and general rules that are simpler to use. And you can use `gcc` itself to generate the header file dependencies rather than tracking them manually (which can lead to all kinds of disaster).  See [the -M option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Comment: I justed saw that in my header file, bal.h, the teacher already include this line : 
#include list.h

When he does that, do i have access to any member of struct list ?

Comment: You don't *need* access to the members. It would be trivial in `list.c` to write functions like `unsigned getLength(List l)` and `char * getValue(List l)`. If your instructor is giving you a `typedef`d pointer in a header file and telling you not to modify it, chances are probably high that this approach is what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler only sees:

```
typedef struct list * List;
```

in an included file, and no definition of `struct list` anywhere else, when the compiler compiles a particular *.c file, and if the code in the *.c file dereferences the `List` pointer to access the members of the `List` struct, an error will be reported because `struct list` has not been defined.

Just because the definition of `struct list` exists in some other file, somewhere else in the same directory, that's compiled separately, doesn't mean that the compiler will know what it is, when it is compiling *this* file.

Compilation of a single *.c file is a completely separate process from the compilation of any other *.c file, and the compiler will only see the definitions of structures, functions and other things, that are explicitly `#include`d, or declared in the `.c` file directly, when compiling *that* particular file.

Comment: Do i need to include list.h AND list.c ?

Comment: The effect of the include command is exactly as if the included file is a part of the file with the include statement. That's what the include statement means. Based on that, you should be able to figure out the answer yourself. Do you want both list.h and list.c to be a part of the file that you're including from?